# If $a$ and $b$ are two odd distinct prime number and if $a>b$, then $a^2-b^2$ can never be divided by

Tags: number-theory

(A) 13
(B) 11
(C) 17
(D) None of the above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, then we want to know whether it's possible to make either $(a+b)$ or $(a-b)$ equal to the multiple of the given numbers (to be its factor).
>
>  $(A)~13$ is possible as we can take $a=23$ and $b=3$ to get $a+b=26$ which is multiple of $13$.
>
>  $(B)~11$ is also possible for $a=19$ and $b=3$.
>
>  $(C)~17$ is also possible for $a=31$ and $b=3$.
>
>  So the answer is **$(D)$**.

Answer (score 2):

A generalisation of athin's answer

> $a^2-b^2$ can be divisible by any number (for some $a$ and $b$).

Explanation

> Even if we take $a$ and $b$ as *consecutive* primes (with no other primes in-between, e.g. 23 and 29; it's a much stronger requirement), according to [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) (at least to its proven part), their difference $a-b$ can be any even number greater or equal to 246. So, for any number $k$, we can find $m$ so $2mk\geqslant246$, and pick $a$ and $b$ so $a-b=2mk$ and is divisible by $k$ (and $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ will be divisible of course).